# Where can I find .net 4.0 SOS.dll?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, debugging, sos

I'm looking for the SOS.dll for .net 4.0.

I have 4.5 installed so my SOS.dll is not valid for the 4.0 builds we create.

Is there somewhere I can find the old version of this file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find it in **C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\sos.dll** path.

For more info visit: [Debugging Managed Code Using the Windows Debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540665%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I would recommend that WindDBG downloads the SOS for you, and for this visit [Automatically Load the Right SOS for the Minidump](http://www.wintellect.com/blogs/jrobbins/automatically-load-the-right-sos-for-the-minidump)

> To get **SOS** automatically downloaded you need to have the Microsoft symbol servers set up in the **_NT_SYMBOL_PATH** environment variable.
>   Then run `!analyze –v`command which will grab the correct version of SOS from Microsoft.
>   The downloaded SOS will be put into your local symbol cache and loaded from there.

Comment: After installing .net 4.5 this is no longer the correct dll

Comment: @playerone see the second link from John Robbins' blog. I've added a quote which briefly describes the process.

Comment: Oh yes, that is very nice.  I will give that a shot.